# How to use predesigned gui elements in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, save

I have been designing Web and Mobile UI for a while and I have found many resources on pre-designed GUIs on the internet. Is there any way in Photoshop where I can save these GUI and to use it on new projects by clicking and dropping it?

Comment: http://pixeldropr.com - Site says cs5 and cs6 but it also works in cc and cc2014, although drag and drop feature doesn't work in those. You can also get it from [creative market](https://creativemarket.com/uiparade/2636-Pixel-Dropr), which is slightly more handy cause you can re-download it through your acc.

Comment: As I side note http://bohemiancoding.com/sketch/ uses symbols to achieve the same thing. The [**symbols**](http://bohemiancoding.com/sketch/support/documentation/07-symbols/) are tied to the document, but otherwise it follows the same idea. –– Side note of a side note: Illustrator also has symbols that you can use in this way.

Comment: This is one of those odd things. People keep asking for template mechanisms when most software have a **save as** and **load** function which is a template mechanism. PS: Most software, +80% will open files on drag and drop, depending on where in the window you drop they either merge, insert or open the file. Not only do you have this in Photoshop but nearly ALL applications within their powers can do similar things.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about using graphic elements in other projects? If so, then yes.

• Download the pre-designed GUI elements.
• Save your GUI elements as a Photoshop document (PSD) and drag said PSD file into your new projects.